# Can I apply for a transit visa in Oman?

Tags: transit-visas, layovers, oman, muscat

I have a flight landing in Muscat, Oman and another taking off in the following 24 hours. I would like to take advantage of my long layover to exit the airport and actually discover Muscat.

I am looking into the visa options I have and I found something appealing, a transit visa, on the [Royal Oman Police website](https://evisa.rop.gov.om/en/types-of-visa) :

Visa type : 23A

Visa name: Airport Transit Visa 1D-3D

Description: Short visit for an airline passenger transiting through Oman on the way to a third country.

However, nowhere could I find a way to apply for this visa. And even though it lies in the "unsponsored" category, [another page of the same website](http://www.rop.gov.om/old/english/dg_pr_visas_transit.asp) mentions that the application should be fulfilled through the carrier (I am not sure I understand the following sentence actually):

> To be granted by competent authority at air way passages to expatriate based on application submit by aviation carrier company entitle the holder to enter the country only once and resident for a maximum period of (72) hour provided that he should have enough money to cover his expenses and valid ticket to continue his travel.

Anyway, I searched the website of Oman Air and I found nothing about transit visas.

So, how can I apply for a transit visa through Oman?

I am a European Union citizen. I found out that I can apply for an eVisa for about 1 month but I'd rather avoid paying 20 rials (45 euros) for a few hours of visiting the city.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Oman made a number of changes to their visa policy in March 2018, shortly before the opening of the new airport in Muscat in April.

I was there a few weeks after that, and was told that they are no longer issuing transit visas. That said, I can not find an official statement to this fact.

They also now require all visitors to apply for a visa in advance using their online system, and as you said this does not currently allow applying for a transit visa.

I suspect the page you have linked to is no longer current - certainly there are a number of other pages on the Royal Oman Police website that are out of date, broken, or "under construction".

If you do decide to apply for a tourist visa the process is simple, and in my case the visa was approved almost immediately (6 minutes!)

Answer (score 3):

As @Doc said, the rules changed recently for tourists in Oman.

As a French national, not resident in GCC country (the Gulf), I could see [multiple unsponsored visas](https://evisa.rop.gov.om/en/types-of-visa) I could apply for and among them:

- 26A Tourist Visit Visa, for 10 days, costing 5 rials
- 26B Tourist Visit Visa, for 30 days, costing 20 rials

One can apply for them online.

Comment: The conditions for the 26A visa appear to have been changed since this question was originally asked.  At the time I answered (as well as when I applied for my visa in April), the only option was a 30 day 26B visa.  However it does now appear that the 26A has been added/changed to be available to "group 1" country citizens.