# Do I need an Oman visa to connect flights on two separate tickets in Muscat?

Tags: indian-citizens, etihad, oman, muscat

I asked this question earlier, but it it wasnt detailed.

1. I am an Indian national and I have a valid US student visa.
2. I have booked my air ticket from India to Chicago (US) in two separate parts.
   (a) Ahmedabad (India) to Muscut (Indigo Airlines)
   ---Collect my luggage and after 6 hour gap re check-in for--
   (2) Muscat to Chicago via Abu Dhabhi (Ettihad Airlines)

Query :

1. Shall I have to exit the muscut airport in order to re check-in for Etihad airlines ? Or collection of luggage from Indigo airlines and re check-in into Etihad airlines for onward journey - all these will be done through internal passage and no need to exit the airport and no need to pass the immigration area ?
2. Whatever the case, shall I have to take a visa/transit-visa for Muscut ? If yes, then will this visa be issued at Muscut airport on my arrival, and generally how much time the process takes ? Or, will it be issued on-line ?
3. Also if I have to apply for a visa online, which category of visa do I need to apply for and what process do I have to follow, I found that 23 a/b are transit visa, but also in 2018 oman changed some rules and regulations and now we cant apply for a transit visa?

Answer (score 2):

1. There is no baggage transfer from Airside. You need to collect the bags yourself, which requires entering oman, which requires a visa. Even if bag transfer is allowed, Indigo will refuse boarding as you are on two different tickets and you don't have a visa for Oman.
2. You can take a visit visa. Transit visa is no longer provided, as per this answer - [Can I apply for a transit visa in Oman?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/117419/can-i-apply-for-a-transit-visa-in-oman) . From the answer, the process is quick.

You can apply here. https://evisa.rop.gov.om/

Comment: +1, but Indigo will not refuse boarding if you have a valid visa for Oman and a flight out.

Comment: @lambshaanxy Clarified.

Comment: i visited the website you stated, the only category I could apply for is 26M. it says that "Can be obtained on arrival at an airport, seaport or land crossing in Oman." but it also states that "Applicant must have a valid hotel booking in Sultanate of Oman."